# ASP .Net Core dependencies giving error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have installed all dependencies and Nuget packages

[image]

But I am getting below error when project created :-

[image]

What can be done for above error resolution?

```
Error       Failed to download package 'Microsoft.Build.Runtime.15.3.409' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.build.runtime/15.3.409/microsoft.build.runtime.15.3.409.nupkg'.
The HTTP request to 'GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.build.runtime/15.3.409/microsoft.build.runtime.15.3.409.nupkg' has timed out after 100000ms.
```

Comment: It would help if you posted the actual error. What happens when you try to build?

Comment: Looks like you need to Restore your nuget packages

Comment: @johnny5 but I have installed required package , image-1 shows that

Comment: @CSharper Yes, but that doesn't mean that they aren't missing from the Packages Folder.  Like if you were doing a fresh install from git.

Comment: You've added the package reference but haven't necessarily installed it to the project.

Comment: What error? I don't see any error on this question

Comment: Error updated in Edit 1

Comment: You probably have a proxy blocking NuGet access

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nuget has a status page which should tell you if it's nuget.org having issues: https://status.nuget.org/.

`The HTTP request to 'GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.build.runtime/15.3.409/microsoft.build.runtime.15.3.409.nupkg' has timed out after 100000ms.` suggestes that the issues are indeed network related as @babak-naffas has already suggested.

Comment: All systems are operational. Last checked 3 minutes ago.

Comment: This is the status

Answer (score 1):

Your issue sounds network related.

Open your browser and try to download the file `https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.build.runtime/15.3.409/microsoft.build.runtime.15.3.409.nupkg` manually.

One of the comments (which has since been removed it seeems) referred to https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/2657 in which had the following comment after some back and forth.

> I spoke to the OP offline and his issue has been resolved. The issue seemed to be related with some proxy settings...

Comment: I am able to download nuget package from browser